# Using multiple CDN links in one StyleBundle

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code:

```
bundles.UseCdn = true;

var fontPath = "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,400,600";

var commonCss = new StyleBundle("~/css/common").Include(
    "~/Content/less/myless.less",
    "~/Content/css/opensans.css", // local copy of the font path above
    "~/Content/less/mylessoverrides.less",
    "~/Content/css/font-awesome.css");

commonCss.Transforms.Add(new CssMinify());
bundles.Add(commonCss);
```

The above code works just fine. However, I would like to load the opensans.css from the CDN link above. I would also like to keep it as one bundle and keep the bundle order intact. The following code will throw an error:

```
var commonCss = new StyleBundle("~/css/common").Include(
    "~/Content/less/myless.less",
    "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,400,600",
    "~/Content/less/mylessoverrides.less",
    "~/Content/css/font-awesome.css");

The URL 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,400,600'
is not valid. Only application relative URLs (~/url) are allowed.
```

One workaround would be to split it up in three bundles but that would be against the entire purpose of bundles:

```
var commonCss1 = new StyleBundle("~/css/common1").Include(
    "~/Content/less/myless.less");

var commonCss2 = new StyleBundle("~/css/common2", fontPath).Include(
    "~/Content/css/opensans.css");

var commonCss3 = new StyleBundle("~/css/common3").Include(
    "~/Content/less/mylessoverrides.less",
    "~/Content/css/font-awesome.css");
```

The ultimate solution would be to do something like:

```
var commonCss = new StyleBundle("~/css/common").Include(
    "~/Content/less/myless.less",
    new { fontPath, "~/Content/css/opensans.css" },
    "~/Content/less/mylessoverrides.less",
    "~/Content/css/font-awesome.css");
```

Has anyone else managed to solve this or managed to extend the framework that would allow for this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use

```
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,400,600");
```

where you want it in the local css file

Comment: Trouble with this is that @import slows down the page - it isn't processed until the parent CSS has fully downloaded. This defeats the whole point of bundling files together

Answer (score 0):

I think this is still under development, check this more recent SO question:
[Absolute URL in ASP bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682671/absolute-url-in-asp-bundle)