# Asp.NET Bundling with absolute URI

Tags: asp.net

There is a website (Asp.NET web forms application) hosted at www.abc.com and all of its static resources including css and js are hosted at resources.abc.com

My question is how can I bundle all the css and scripts? Is there any way to buldle Absolute URL scripts and styles ?

Thanks

Comment: Please read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification and come back with your concrete doubts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Absolute URL in ASP bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682671/absolute-url-in-asp-bundle)